# sam local start-api debugging typescript using vscode debugger

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vscode-debugger, aws-sam

`sam local start-api` takes a flags  `--debugger-path` , `--debug-port` . But i am yet to see example of usage of these for debugging purposes.

I have a typescript project with a lot of lambdas; my debugging process has been :
`sam local start-api` followed by calling specific service from postman and reading the logs from console.logs i have put in multiple places. if i want to see some object i have to JSON.stringify it and log it.....

This is painful process and i have yet able to setup the project to work with vscode debugger using typescript. all my break points get ignored (they are not grey)

i have this configuration in vscode launch.json, but it does not work. I was running it after i do `sam local start-api` .  It starts and terminates in about 30seconds.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to SAM Local API",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 5858,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
```

When a service is called from postman; sam mounts the specific lambda in docker container and runs the lambda. How can i make vscode break when the current lambda is mounted in docker container?  I assume debuger must be running and waiting for me to make the call from postman..and when i do sam mounts the corresponding lambda in a container...and then the running debugger connects to the debug session from the container???

Is this were `--debugger-path` , `--debug-port`  become useful?